# How can I redefine the way ANSI colors are shown in a terminal emulator in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'd like to redefine the actual colors that ANSI escape sequences show, i.e. I'd like to personalize what "light red" means and render it as, say, orange.

Is there any terminal emulator that works under linux that allows me to do this? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Gnome terminal and Konsole allow you to select amongst colour schemata, controlling what the 16 colours display as, and Gnome terminal allows customization of the individial colours in the "Custom" scheme.